# Redirect AMP files on nginx

Tags: nginx, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm trying to make redirect on nginx but unfortunately it doesn't work.
What I'd like to achieve, it is to redirect amp files on mobile.

What I'd like to do :

from

https://www.example.com/uri-759.html

to

https://www.example.com/uri-759-amp.html

What I did as redirect

```
if ($mobile_redirect = perform) {

    redirect ^(.*)(\.html)$ $1-amp$2 permanent;
}
```

what I obtain

https://www.example.com/uri-759-amp-amp-amp-amp-amp-amp-amp-amp.html

Does someone have a solution to perform this redirection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind assertion to avoid matching the rewritten URI.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)(?<!-amp)(\.html)$ $1-amp$2 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) for more.